# How to handle signals/events in Java

Tags: java, android, signal-handling

Can any tell me how signals are handled in Java? I have a situation where I need to signal an event/signal to a thread from application main ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On android you can use the Handler class to send messages across threads.
[Here is the Handler class description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)  and a [code sample](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/500.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Java usually notifications are passed either as an Event, meaning that some action has happened, such as a button has been clicked or as an Exception, meaning that something went wrong, such as the attempt to access an invalid location in an array.

Another approach would be to use `volatile` variables as flags.

A more language agnostic approach would be to use flags, maybe some sort of Semaphore (even though these are usually more used to regulate access across competing threads).

You could also use sockets I would suppose, but these are usually used for inter process communication.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it...

**Events :** `When some action take place.`

**Event-Handling :** `To do certain actions on the basis of the Event.`

```
Eg: 

   Button - Button is an Event Source

   Action - Button Pressed

   Pressing of button generates an Event, which is needed to be Handled..
```

**Exceptions :**`When Something unexpectedly take place.`

`Throwable --> Exception --> IOException & InterruptedException --> Checked and UnChecked` `Exceptions`

```
Eg: 
      Making a Socket Connection to the Server 

If the connection to the Server fails it leads to 
UnknowHostException which in need to be Handled..
this is called Exception Handling..

    We handle the exception using try/catch blocks
```

Comment: Brilliant !!!  I would like to know how can use the same when communicating with two threads? say I read some data from one thread and then notify write thread to do some job. I went through some blogs where in semaphore is recommended to use for wait and notify calls, it also makes sense since data between two threads need to be synchronized.  Is there any other events that we can raise which doesnt need synchronization? just to notify other thread?

Comment: If you dont want to use synchronization, but want to use the wait-notify mechanism, then go for the ReerrantLock() in java.util.concurrent package and use lock()-unlock(), along with Condition Interface, where u can use await-singal mechanism, And just one more thing...if you find this really brilliant, why is my point still 0 at this answer...hahaha....!!